# Python invalid character in identifier

Tags: python

haciendo un programa con menu, una de las opciones llama a la funcion "grilla", que a su vez llama a otras 2 funciones "asignar" y "coordenadas". No encuentro error alguno y sin embargo sigue apareciendo "python invalid character in identifier" en las lineas al final de esas 2 ultimas funciones. Alguien puede ayudarme?

```py
def grilla (info):
    lista=[]
    frec={}
    for i in range (len(info)):
        lat=float(info[i][5])
        long=float(info[i][6])
        lat=asignar(lat)
        long=asignar(long)
        coordenadas=(lat,",", long)
        lista.append(coordenadas)
    for elemento in lista:
        frec[elemento]=frec.get(elemento,0)+1
    coordenadas(frec)

def asignar(value):
    valor=(value%10)*10
#   si valor==0 por defecto lo tira al cuadrante positivo
    if valor!=value or value==0:  
        if value>0 or value==0:
            valor+=10
        elif value<0:
            valor=valor-10
    return valor​​

def coordenadas(dicc):
    def ubicacion(dicc, value):
        return [key for key, val in dicc.items() if val == value]
​
    cantidad=max(dicc.values())
    zona=ubicacion(frec,cantidad)
​
    print("La zona mas poblada se encuenta en las coordenadas: ", zona)
    print("En esa zona hay ", cantidad, " chitas")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Diagnosis

Aunque el código a primera vista parece correcto, el mensaje de error parece indicar que pueda contener caracteres invisibles que estén causando problemas.

Si copio el código de tu pregunta, lo pego en un fichero y hago un volcado hexadecimal del mismo (con herramientas como `xxd`, o un editor hexadecimal), vemos cosas como:

```
00000250: 3130 0a20 2020 2072 6574 7572 6e20 7661  10.    return va
00000260: 6c6f 72e2 808b e280 8b0a 0a64 6566 2063  lor........def c
00000270: 6f6f 7264 656e 6164 6173 2864 6963 6329  oordenadas(dicc)
```

Aquí se observa, en la segunda línea, que tras el `return valor` aparece la secuencia de bytes `e2 80 8b`, repetida dos veces (`e2 80 8b e2 80 8b`) y tras ella aparece ya `0a 0a` que es el código de los dos retornos de carro.

La secuencia `e2 80 8b` es la codificación en UTF-8 del carácter unicode [U+200B](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) que es el "espacio de ancho cero".

Por tanto, entre la `r` final de `return valor` y el retorno de carro, hay metidos ahí dos espacios de ancho cero. Estos caracteres son completamente invisibles en el editor (aunque si te pones tras la `r` en esa línea puedes borrarlos pulsando `supr` dos veces). Pero no son invisibles para Python, que no los admite como parte de un nombre de variable.

No es el único lugar en que aparece la secuencia `e2 80 8b`, es decir, que tienes más "espacios de ancho cero" metidos por aquí y por allá.

### Posible causa

Quizás has copiado y pegado el código de algún sitio. Este tipo de "cosas raras" con caracteres invisibles suele aparecer cuando pegas texto desde un pdf.

### Solución

Es difícil corregir este problema una vez se produce, debido a que esos caracteres son invisibles y ni siquiera ocupan un hueco en el editor (debido a su "ancho cero").

No obstante puedes intentar usar la opción "Buscar y reemplazar" y ver si tu editor te permite introducir códigos Unicode en el campo de búsqueda, reemplazándolos entonces por la cadena vacía para hacerlos desaparecer.

También puedes hacer un mini-programa python que te corrija el problema, como el siguiente:

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    entrada = f.read()

salida = entrada.replace("\u200b", "")
print("Eliminados {} caracteres invisibles!".format(len(entrada) - len(salida)))

with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(salida)
```

Lo usarías así:

```sh
# Hagamos primero una copia de tu fichero, por si acaso
$ cp tu_programa.py tu_programa_original.py

# Ahora ejecutamos el script anterior, guardado en arreglar.py
$ python arreglar.py tu_programa.py
Eliminados 4 caracteres invisibles!
```

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que en las líneas que comentas hay un espacio blanco que Python interpreta mal.

Así queda el código corregido:

```
def grilla (info):
    lista=[]
    frec={}
    for i in range (len(info)):
        lat=float(info[i][5])
        long=float(info[i][6])
        lat=asignar(lat)
        long=asignar(long)
        coordenadas=(lat,",", long)
        lista.append(coordenadas)
    for elemento in lista:
        frec[elemento]=frec.get(elemento,0)+1
    coordenadas(frec)
    return

def asignar(value):
    valor=(value%10)*10
#   si valor==0 por defecto lo tira al cuadrante positivo
    if valor!=value or value==0:
        if value>0 or value==0:
            valor+=10
        elif value<0:
            valor=valor-10
    return valor

def coordenadas(dicc):
    def ubicacion(dicc, value):
        return [key for key, val in dicc.items() if val == value]

    cantidad=max(dicc.values())
    zona=ubicacion(frec,cantidad)

    print("La zona mas poblada se encuenta en las coordenadas: ", zona)
    print("En esa zona hay ", cantidad, " chitas")

def grilla (info):
    lista=[]
    frec={}
    for i in range (len(info)):
        lat=float(info[i][5])
        long=float(info[i][6])
        lat=asignar(lat)
        long=asignar(long)
        coordenadas=(lat,",", long)
        lista.append(coordenadas)
    for elemento in lista:
        frec[elemento]=frec.get(elemento,0)+1
    coordenadas(frec)

def asignar(value):
    valor=(value%10)*10
#   si valor==0 por defecto lo tira al cuadrante positivo
    if valor!=value or value==0:
        if value>0 or value==0:
            valor+=10
        elif value<0:
            valor=valor-10
    return valor

def coordenadas(dicc):
    def ubicacion(dicc, value):
        return [key for key, val in dicc.items() if val == value]
# Aquí había un espacio
    cantidad=max(dicc.values())
    zona=ubicacion(frec,cantidad)
# Aquí había un espacio
    print("La zona mas poblada se encuenta en las coordenadas: ", zona)
    print("En esa zona hay ", cantidad, " chitas")
```

Answer (score 0):

revisa bien que el código se ha copiado de una parte a la otra y la otra parte aparece con espacios adicionales por lo cual debes usar algún visualizador web o control de tu editor de código (Visual Code, pychat etc)
Recomendado:
https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y después de retirado los caracteres especiales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).